# How to beautify jupyter output, especially with alignment?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I'm learning python pandas programming with jupyter notebook. I see from video clips that the output of pandas series is neat, with column alignment, such as the one below:

[image]

But when I learn from my own jupyter, the output is rather messy:

[image]

May I know how to change the fonts and style? I like the layout shown in the teaching video. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Did you adjust the font settings prior to this? I suspect you need a nonproportional , a.k.a. monospaced font.  And I think you did adjust the fonts prior to this, or your machine has limited ones, because your `In` and `Out` don't look typical.  You don't specify if you are using the classic notebook interface or JupyterLab. Both ways are kind of covered in this thread [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14319#issue-1651639023) though. How did you install. If you didn't use the Anaconda Distribution, I'd suggest that and maybe you'd have more normal settings as a result?

Comment: I installed jupyter notebook from anacoda. Seems to be classic notebook interface.

Comment: Okay, then look for the css stuff. Like I said, your fonts aren't typical. Is your system limited in some other way? Did you mess with your system fonts a lot? If you want to compare, you can go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda) and hit `launch binder`. When the session spins up, run in a new cell `import pandas as pd` and then try running the demo code at the Pandas ['pandas.DataFrame.stack' page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). I think it will work because the fonts will be served from the remote computer, **I hope**.